# share numpy array (opencv frame) between python and cpp using mmap shared memory in python

Tags: python, c++, shared-memory

I have a code in cpp that reads from shared memory like this :

```html
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\Test");

int _tmain()
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPCTSTR pBuf;

   hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
                   FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
                   FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
                   szName);               // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());
      return 1;
   }

   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
               FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
               0,
               0,
               BUF_SIZE);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());

      CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }

   MessageBox(NULL, pBuf, TEXT("Process2"), MB_OK);

   UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

   CloseHandle(hMapFile);

   return 0;
}
```

and have a numpy frame (opencv python) that produces frames. I want to share them with this cpp code to read that. 
some codes like:

```html
shm = mmap.mmap(0, len(A.flatten()),tagname="Global\\Test")
```

this reads that but the structure of matrix not kept. so what should I do for it?
thanks for helps

Comment: shared memory is plain bytes. There is no structure information.